# How to get unnamed elements from an external webpage using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

At the moment I'm trying to get an element off an external website using AJAX, so far I've (hopefully) managed to get the page:

```
var xmlhttp;
var version;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    version=xmlhttp.innerHTML;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Minecraft_Wiki",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Now I just need to find a way to get the contents:

```
<dd> Current PC version: 
<b>
<a href="/wiki/Version_history#1.2.5" title="Version history">
1.2.5
</a>
</b>
</dd>
```

I've checked the source code of the url and sadly the element I want is unnamed (Has no id=" "), so is it still possible to do so? And if so, how? Thanks

Comment: How can anyone say how to select the element if we don't know what element you want to select?

Comment: Also, have you verified you can get even the body element of the remote page? Most modern browsers don't support cross-domain AJAX, which means you'll get security exceptions.

Comment: @GGG It's the current PC version in this wiki, if that's what you mean. http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Minecraft_Wiki It isn't labeled though however

Comment: @user1320911 - Why don't you update the question with an example of the HTML snippet? The more detail in the question and the less poking around other sites we have to do, the better your answers will be. :)

Comment: @jmort253 I haven't thought about that. Is there a way to check? I apologise in advance, I know almost nothing about AJAX but am trying to learn at the moment

Comment: `[].filter.call(document.links, function(a) { return a.title == "Version history" }).shift()` ... that works on http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Minecraft_Wiki, in the console.

Comment: @GGG Awesome, thanks :D Just tried that through the console and it worked. Sorry to bother you again however but would you happen to know how to get that into html? And if the cross-domain AJAX would work?

Comment: @user1320911 No, I think you're out of luck with the cross-domain stuff. You'll probably need to proxy it off of the server.

Comment: @GGG ok, but thanks anyway. I was possibly thinking about using an iframe to get it and possibly filter it, but not sure if that would work.

Comment: @user1320911 nope, you'll get shut down by the same-origin policy there as well.

Comment: @GGG Same-origin? I managed to get it working with the iFrame but is it illegal?

Comment: @user1320911 this is worth reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: @GGG Ah, thanks. That clears up a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're making a cross-domain request, so unless you're using a browser that allows cross-domain AJAX, this is most likely not going to work for you without using a server-side proxy.

However, to answer your original question, you don't need an id attribute to access an element. While helpful, you can access an element in any number of ways.

**Class Selectors**

```
var col = document.getElementsByClassName("the-class");
```

Then loop through the collection until you find the element you want.

**jQuery Selectors:**

[jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) are perhaps the easiest way to handle DOM manipulations and get access to the element you are interested in:

```
// example of an attribute selector:

var exampleHTML = $('div[title="example"]).html();
```

There is also XPath, but from my experience jQuery CSS Selectors are more modern, robust, and help speed up the development process.